# Javascript ~ Calling a function inside a Variable

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I have a variable that is the functions name. I want to be able to call on that function from the variable.

```
var CircuitBox= document.getElementById("QLCS")
var CircuitNumber = CircuitBox.selectedIndex;
var circuit = CircuitBox.options[CircuitNumber].value;

// This Variable takes on the functions name that id like to call       
circuit;
```

Cheers!

Comment: I think you mean JavaScript.  Java and JavaScript are not the same or even related.

Comment: If it's a global function then: `window[circuit]()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript object properties can be accessed via there name as a string by using bracket notation, eg:

```
var propertyVal = myObj["propertyName"];
```

And since globally scoped members are actually properties of the Global object, you can get the properties from the window object (which is a reference to the Global object).  So, if your drop down list contains values that map to function names in the global scope, you can call that function like this:

```
window[circuit]();
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways.

You can try `window[circuit]()` if it is a global function. The other option is to use `eval`, but `eval` is evil. So to avoid the evilness of `eval`, a better way might be to maintain a map of handlers:

```
var handlers = {
   someValue: function() {
      ...
   },
   otherValue: function() {
      ...
   }
};
```

In this map, you're associating `someValue` and `otherValue` with anonymous functions. So assuming that your select box contains the options `someValue` and `otherValue`, the appropriate function will be called based on what they select.

Then all you have to do is `handlers[circuit]()`.